# Tick label breaking(word-wrap)

Tags: label, jqplot, textlabel

I'm using jqPlot
Look at the right-bottom corner

Left side is correct, but the right side isn't.

[image]
**There is a way to fix word-wrap on tick labels?**

EDIT:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart-line', [[["2013-03-22",1],["2013-03-23",0],["2013-03-24",0],["2013-03-25",2],["2013-03-26",19],["2013-03-27",7],["2013-03-28",4]]]
      , {
          title: 'Total de alertas por dia',

          seriesDefaults: {
            fill:true,
                    color: 'steelblue',
              rendererOptions: {

                 smooth: true
              },
              pointLabels:{ show:true }
          },
          axes: {
            xaxis: {

               renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
               tickOptions:{
                    formatString: '%F',//'%Q',
                    textColor: 'black',
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    labelPosition: 'auto'
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                min:0,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            }
          }
        });
```

EDIT:
Here is HTML

```
<style>
.ComBordaRedonda {
    border:1px solid #dadada;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
</style>
<div class="ComBordaRedonda" style = "float: right;background-color:#FFFFFF;width: 57%; height: 300px;">
    <div id = "chart-line" style = "width: 90%; height: 95%;margin:auto">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use to plot the graph?

Comment: Sorry man... now is there!

Comment: That code runs fine for me - I don't get the word wrap issue. Have you applied any CSS to `chart-line`?

Comment: Yes.. I have some style. How do you do? Can you give a JSFiddle or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't reproduce this. Do you think you could create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: JSFiddle doens't give me the option to include the jqPLot. Can you download this zip with the example? https://www.box.com/s/a9hjda6jnh52c8tluxyb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.
I forgot to include the css of jqPlot in the page.

thanks nick_w!